# undefined method `review_groups'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an undefined message for @show.review_groups.  Currently trying to iterate through review groups to pull from the db schema

```
        @show.review_groups.each do |review_group| 
            data = []
            data << review_group.try(:group_name)
            data << review_group.try(:limit)
            data << review_group.metric(:approved, true)
            data << review_group.metric(:approved_first_tier, true)
            data << review_group.metric(:pending_review, true)
            data << review_group.role(presentation.id)
            data << review_group.metric(:declined, true)

            total = review_group.metric(:approved, true).to_f / review_group.try(:limit).to_f * 100
            data << total 

            AxlsxTools.add_row(data)
```

Comment: where you have defined `@show.review_groups` instance variable please can you share more code

Comment: `@show` is `nil` probably...